# c++ how to create object with class Template

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have the following code.

**Main.cpp:**

```
Warehouse<Base<int>> arm(1, 1, 1, 1);
arm.createSubBase(1,1,1);
```

**Warehouse.h:**

```
private:
 vector<Base<T>*> whouse;
public :
 void createSubBase(int, int, int);

template <class T> 
void Warehouse<T>::createSubBase(int,int,int) {
  Base<T>* dN = new SubBase<T>(int,int,int,int); ***<-ERROR MESSAGE:" in file included from"***
     whouse.push_back(dN);
}
```

**Base.h:**

```
template <class T>
class Base {
private:
 int I,a,b,c;
public :
  Base(int,int,int,int);
}

template <class T>
Base<T>::Base(int i, int a, int b, int c) {
    this -> I = i;
    this -> a= a;
    this -> b= b;
    this -> c = c;
}
```

**SubBase.h:**

```
template <class T>
class SubBase: public Base<T> {
public:
  SubBase(int, int, int,int);
}
template <class T>
SubBase<T>::SubBase(int, int, int , int) : Depositos<T>(int,int,int,int) {...}
```

Does anyone know why I get this error message? I don't understand why not let me create that `Base<T> * b = new subbase<T> ( int , int , int );`.

Answer (score 1):

Function arguments need to be expressions that give the argument's value, not type names like `int`. So the problematic line should be

```
Base<T>* dN = new SubBase<T>(a,b,c,d);
```

replacing `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` with whatever arguments you want to pass to the constructor. Similarly, the constructor needs to pass valid arguments to its base class (which also needs to be specified with the right name). Perhaps you want to pass the arguments straight through:

```
SubBase<T>::SubBase(int a, int b, int c, int d) : Base<T>(a,b,c,d) {...}
```

You're also missing `;` after the class definitions.

After fixing these errors, the code compiles for me: http://ideone.com/mb0AOP